# Появление и сворачивание поля ввода на JS

Tags: javascript, css, form, frontend

Мне нужно написать поле для ввода, которое при нажатии на рядом находящийся элемент появляется, а при нажатии куда-либо вне поля скрывалось.

Разметка:

```
<form class="nav__search">
    // То самое поле ввода, которое должно возникнуть при клике
    // на элемент ниже и исчезнуть при клике вне этого поля
    <input class="nav__search-input" type="search">
    // Вот на этот элемент и нужно нажать, чтобы поле ввода появилось
    <img src="nav__search-img.png" alt="" class="nav__search-img">
</form>
```

Стили:

```
.nav__search-input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: none;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Скрипт для появления из ниоткуда поля ввода:

```
$(".nav__search").click(function() {
    $(".nav__search-input").animate({
        width: "386px",
        height: "74px"
    },200).focus();
});
```

Вот этот скрипт я хотел предназначить для того, чтобы скрывать поле

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    var container = $(".nav__search-input");
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.animate({
            width: "0",
            height: "0"
        },200).html('');
    }
});
```

Но, когда я нажимаю на кнопочку, то у меня срабатывают обе анимации, то есть поле начинает появляться и сразу же скрываться. Я то понял в чём причина: класс .nav__search-img находится как раз вне поля ввода, что и заставляет срабатывать обе анимации одновременно.

В общем как мне согласовать эти 2 скрипта? Или какие есть альтернативные варианты решения этого вопроса **с применением JS**?

Comment: оба обработчика событий поставьте на форму, при клике определяйте цель клика по ее особенностям: разные классы, разные теги, разные доп. атрибуты и т.д., после чего  - выполните желаемый код

Answer (score 2):

События распространяются на все родительские элементы если они произошли в дочерних. `document` является родительским для элемента с классом `.nav__search`. Когда вы кликаете на него, событие `onclick` получает и `document`.
Поэтому нужно приостановить выполнение обработчика `onclick`.

```
$(".nav__search").click(function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault(); // Отменяет событие(если оно отменяемое), без остановки дальнейшего распространения этого события.
   event.stopPropagation(); // Прекращает дальнейшую передачу текущего события. 
   $(".nav__search-input")
     .animate({
        width: "386px",
         height: "74px"
     }, 200)
     .focus();
});
```